# Maximum Child Elements error in lighthouse

Tags: html

I have the following select where I get that I have maximum child elements:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
 <div class="form-group">                                                                            
  <label for="Tipoproatv">Tipo de Produto </label>
   <select type="text" name="Tipoproatv" id="Tipoproatv" class="form-control" data-placeholder="Selecione opções" disabled>
    <?php
     $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM raddb.Produtos ORDER BY Produto ASC");
     $sql->execute();
     while($row=$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      echo '<option value="' . $row['Id']. '">'. $row['Produto'].'</option>';
    }
   ?>
  </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

The error I receive in Chrome's Lighthouse is as follows:

> Maximum Child Elements   select#Tipoproatv.form-control